# How can I make a Combine.js file load async

Tags: javascript, performance

I have created a combined.js file page with all my inline and other scripts into one file...

How can I load these scripts asynchronously into my page? - I have done this because Google and Yahoo recommends this to speed-up my website loading.

I have already placed the file in my footer.php (I am using wordpress using wp_enqueue_script) but without async or defer tags, as it seem like I will have to hardcode these into my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5 you can use the 'async' attribute you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async) the support for it:

```
<script async src="myJavascript.js"></script>
```

The old way to do it, is like this:

```
<script>
 var res = document.createElement('script'); 
 res.src = "myJavascript.js";
 var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 script.parentNode.insertBefore(res, script);
</script>
```

This way has more support than you will ever need.

Comment: Thanks David, The first line of code works 100% - I have actually wp_enqueue_script twice into the page and one had async and the other not, and this is why I kept on seeing the error! - Thanks a million